# Trapping class definition via Proxy in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, metaprogramming, es6-class, es6-proxy

Is it possible to trap `extends`? Or to trap definitions inside a class? Eg:

```
class B extends A {
    method1( ) { }
    static method2( ) { }
}
```

Is there any way to trap the events that:

- `B` extended `A`.
- `method1( )` was defined on `B.prototype`
- `method2( )` was defined on `B`.

None of the existing mechanisms seem to work. Tried `setPrototypeOf` and `defineProperty` traps.

Comment: Where do you want to trap these thing? `B` doesn't exist at one moment and is already defined at another. Explaining your case would probably help.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve by trapping extend?  I'm guessing that there may be other ways to solve it that we could help with.

Comment: Use cases are similar to why one would want to trap `defineProperty`: auto-run code when something is defined on an object. Since the `defineProperty` traps weren't triggered, I was checking if `extends` can be trapped. I don't have a strong use case for `extends` trapping otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When class `B` extends class `A`, it gets its `prototype` object. So you can define a Proxy with a trap on `get` et check if the property being accessed is `"prototype"`.

```js
class A {}

PA = new Proxy(A, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    console.log('get', property)
    if (property == 'prototype')
      console.info('extending %o, prototype=%s', target, target.prototype)
    return target[property]
  }
})

class B extends PA {}
```

Comment: @Gubbi note that the prototype could be accessed in other situations so be careful, maybe you'll need to check further depending on your use case.